# DetailsView with SQLDataSource, display two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource, detailsview

I need to display some details on DetailsView from two tables.

I have table: `orders [orderId , userId_relat]`
and table: `users  [userId , userName]`

i have the next SQLDataSource SELECT command:

```
    SelectCommand="SELECT [orderId], [userId_relat],  
FROM [orders] WHERE ([userId_relat] = @userId) >
```

i want to show the outpot:

> orderId  ..........  userName

Instead of:

> orderId .... userId_relat

It is possible? if yes... how?

SQLDataSource control supports one select only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User SQL join...

```
SELECT orders.orderId, users.username
FROM orders
INNER JOIN users
on orders.userId_relat = users.userId
WHERE userId = @userId
```

If you need tutorials, go to these links:

http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php

“Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.”

Comment: Your welcome! I'm glad I could help. Please check as answered if it helped you! Thanks!